# Can't use slideout.min.js on old versions of Android (Cordova)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I get a blank screen when I try and run the app I have developed using Cordova on old versions of Android with this error message: Disabled addJavascriptInterface() bridge since Android version is old.if I comment out the

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/slideout.min.js"></script>
```

It runs fine (obviously minus the menu I have created.) Is there anyway around this?

Comment: [link]http://s9.postimg.org/v2v2e6o9b/snapshot1.png

Comment: Please add Cordova version, Android version and slideout version that you're using!

Comment: Using this slideout(can't find a version in the documentation): [link](https://github.com/Mango/slideout/blob/master/dist/slideout.min.js) Cordova Version: 5.0.0 and Android Studio: 1.3

Comment: What about the Android version of the phone/emulator you are using?

Comment: I've tried on a few devices it doesn't seem to work on 4.3 or below. It works fine on 4.4